# How to write row_number with partition by in qlik table?

Tags: row, row-number, qliksense

I want to write below row_number logic in qlik table. How can it be written?

```
row_number() over (partition by job.jobnumber order by cast(hist.EventTimeStamp as Date) asc) as row_id
```

How to write partition by in row number in qlik sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the [`AutoNumber()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/CounterFunctions/autonumber.htm), which returns an incrementing integer for each unique value provided grouped by an "AutoID." In your case, you can use it like so:

```
[Jobs]:
Load
    AutoNumber(RowNo(), [job.jobnumber]) as [row_id]
  , [job.jobnumber]
  , [hist.EventTimeStamp]
  , [EventType]
  , [EventValue]
Resident [data]
  Order By [hist.EventTimeStamp] asc
;
```

**EDIT:**

Come to think of it, you can also use the [`Window()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/WindowFunctions/Window.htm) to achieve partition functionality in Qlik. It's a relatively new function so you may or may not have it at your disposal depending on the version of Qlik you're using.

You would use it like this:

```
[Jobs]:
Load
    Window(RecNo(), [job.jobnumber], 'ASC', [hist.EventTimeStamp])
  , [job.jobnumber]
  , [hist.EventTimeStamp]
  , [EventType]
  , [EventValue]
Resident [data];
```